# Rstudio c++ code diagnosis error

Tags: rstudio

I changed my working station to a new computer and installed R, Rtools, Rstudio and Rcpp, etc. When testing my installation, I simply created a new C++ file as this:

[image]

Then there will be a default C++ code to illustrate the use of Rcpp, but after I saved the file as `test.cpp`, the code diagnosis in Rstudio gave me the red mark:

[image]

This should not happen because I can compile the code and `sourceCpp` with no problem, and the function is correctional displayed in R. I was using the latest Rstudio, and then I changed to an older version, but the red mark still exited.

So I'm wondering how could that happen. I don't want to turn off the code diagnosis for C++ file since it's useful, but for sure I don't want every line of my code being marked. Does anyone know what's going wrong in my case?

Comment: Add output from `sessionInfo()`, `RStudio.Version()$version`, and if on Windows `Sys.getenv("PATH")`

Comment: What made you think posting screenshots would do any good?

Comment: Also, it simply does not happen on more recent versions of RStudio. I recommend the [daily builds](https://dailies.rstudio.com/) for a variety of reasons.  Lastly, this has nothing to do with Rcpp itself so I will remove the tag.